# Python. DB-API(PyMySQL, PostgreSQL, ...). Курсоры(cursor = connect.cursor()). Один курсор на все запросы, или один курсор на один запрос?

Tags: python, база-данных, python-3.x, cursor

К примеру **PyMySQL**. Как будет правильнее использовать курсоры?

**Вариант 1**:

```
connect = pymysql.connect()
cursor = connect.cursor()
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO user(name) VALUE('%s')', ('John',))
last_id = cursor.lastrowid
cursor.execute('SELECT name FROM user')
result = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.close()
```

**Вариант 2**:

```
connect = pymysql.connect()
cursor = connect.cursor()
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO user(name) VALUE('%s')', ('John',))
last_id = cursor.lastrowid
cursor.close()
cursor = connect.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT name FROM user')
result = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.close()
```

Т.е. можно ли использовать один созданный курсор для все запросов, или создавать каждый раз новый курсор для нового запроса?

И, если использовать один курсор для одного типа запроса с разными данными? Например, **вариант 3**:

```
connect = pymysql.connect()
cursor = connect.cursor()
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO user(name) VALUE('%s')', ('John',))
last_id_1 = cursor.lastrowid
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO city(name) VALUE('%s')', ('Moskow',))
last_id_2 = cursor.lastrowid
cursor.close()

cursor = connect.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT name FROM user')
result_1 = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.execute('SELECT name FROM city')
result_2 = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.close()
```

Какой вариант лучше/правильнее использовать(и с точки зрения производительности тоже)?

Comment: лучше первый вариант или можно пойти еще дальше и использовать [`connection pooling`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connection-pooling.html)

Comment: @MaxU, т.е. можно создать только один курсор и всегда работать через него? Например, веб-сервер, который всегда работает: в начале мы создаем курсор и все время работы сервера посылаем запросы и получаем ответы(если есть) только через этот один курсор. Это будет корректно? Не будет никаких ошибок, неверных данных, и т.д. в процессе работы?

Comment: Это зависит от вашего приложения и от нагрузки- одного может оказаться слишком мало... почитайте о “Connection pooling”

Comment: @MaxU, я понял, спасибо!